# Add N Pixel Buffer to Polygon (Region/Path) While Maintaining Centroid in C#

Tags: c#, geometry, system.drawing, polygons, scaletransform

**The Problem:** Add n pixel buffer to an existing polygon (guaranteed to be closed, non-overlapping, and points in clockwise formation) while maintaining the centroid of the polygon.

**Current:** I have a PolyRegion class which contains a System.Drawing Path and System.Drawing Region. When I instantiate the class I'd add the factor buffer to the path and scale/transform it. The result is offset instead if scaled with respect to the centroid.

**Example:** The green polygon is the original. When I scale it by factor of n, I get/want the purple polygon (centered on centroid).

[image]

**Question:** How can I scale with respect to the centroid? AM I better off scaling each point in the point array or scaling the Path/Region?

**Code:**

```
public PolyRegion(Int32 Id, List<Point> Points)
{
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Points = Points;
    this.Path = this.CreatePath();

    float factor = 10;
    float wScale = (float)((this.Path.GetBounds().Width - factor) / this.Path.GetBounds().Width);
    float hScale = (float)((this.Path.GetBounds().Height - factor) / this.Path.GetBounds().Height);
    Matrix transformMatrix = new Matrix();
    transformMatrix.Scale(wScale, hScale);
    this.Path.Transform(transformMatrix);

    this.Region = new Region(this.Path);
    this.Area = CalculateArea();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a mathematical/geometric issue than a programming one:

1) Translate figure from centroid position (x,  y) to (0,0) coordinate

2) Scale by the factor you desire.

3) Translate back to original centroid.

Comment: Since you don't specify it in your code, I would calculate (x,y) as the mean of all the points from your figure.

Comment: Why is #1 necessary? Why not just scale then re-position? Seems there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: Usually graphics algorithms deal with matrixes, since it offers an homogeneous tool for all transformations, and nowadays HW is optimized. Of course, the way you suggest is possible for this particular situation; if centroid is `(x, y)`, after aplying scale `k` it will be `(kx, ky)`. The calculus of the translation needed is left as an exercise to the reader :-).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ditch matrix and region scale and transforms and go with a more pure approach.

First I calculate the centroid of my polgon:

```
private Point GetCentroid()
{
int centroidX = 0;
int centroidY = 0;
int pointCount = this.Points.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
{
centroidX = centroidX + this.Points[i].X;
centroidY = centroidY + this.Points[i].Y;
}

centroidX = centroidX / pointCount;
centroidY = centroidY / pointCount;

return new Point(centroidX, centroidY);
}
```

Then loop through each point and buffer it by S and T (my buffer factor):

```
private List<Point> GetBufferedPoints()
{
int c = this.Centroid.X;
int d = this.Centroid.Y;
int s = this.BufferFactor;
int t = this.BufferFactor;
int pointCount = this.Points.Count();
PointsBuffered = new List<Point>();

for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
{
int x = this.Points[i].X;
int y = this.Points[i].Y;
PointsBuffered.Add(new Point((s * (x - c)) + c, (t * (y - d)) + d));
}

return PointsBuffered;
}
```

Result:

[image]